# Material Design Typography and Snackbars

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme, android-snackbar, material-components-android

Per https://material.io/develop/android/theming/typography/, I’ve been customizing my app’s style by modifying the textAppearanceX attributes.  Does anyone know which attribute to customize to style an app’s Snackbars or where this is documented?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With the Material Components Library you can customize the `textAppearance` used by the text and the button through the app theme:

Just use the **`snackbarButtonStyle`** and **`snackbarTextViewStyle`** attributes to define **globally** in the app:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">

    <!-- Style to use for action button within a Snackbar in this theme. -->
    <item name="snackbarButtonStyle">@style/Custom.TextButton.Snackbar</item>

    <!-- Style to use for message text within a Snackbar in this theme. -->
    <item name="snackbarTextViewStyle">@style/Custom.Snackbar.TextView</item>
    ....
</style>
```

Then for the **button** you can define a custom style applying the `android:textAppearance` attribute

```
  <style name="Custom.TextButton.Snackbar" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Snackbar">
      <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/snackbar_button_textappearance</item>
  </style>
```

It is just an example:

```
  <style name="snackbar_button_textappearance"  parent="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
  </style>
```

For the **text** you can do something similar with:

```
  <style name="Custom.Snackbar.TextView" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar.TextView">
     <item name="android:textAppearance">......</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Pls **note**:

- `snackbarButtonStyle` attribute requires the version **1.1.0**
- `snackbarTextViewStyle` attribute requires the version **1.2.0**.